# keras agents fails in DQNAgent using PQC during clonation for target

Tags: programming, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, tfq

I have some issues using keras-rl2 with tensorflow_quantum and VQC (using identical architecture as https://www.tensorflow.org/quantum/tutorials/quantum_reinforcement_learning)

**After the creation of the model and DqnAgent, in *dqn.compile*:**

```
   ############################################################
   def generate_model_Qlearning(qubits, n_layers, n_actions, observables, target):

   qubits = cirq.GridQubit.rect(1, n_qubits)
   ops = [cirq.Z(q) for q in qubits]
   observables = [ops[0]*ops[1], ops[2]*ops[3]] # Z_0*Z_1 for 
   action 0 and Z_2*Z_3 for action 1

   input_tensor = tf.keras.Input(shape=(len(qubits), ), 
   dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, name='input')
   re_uploading_pqc = ReUploadingPQC(qubits, n_layers, 
           observables, activation='tanh')([input_tensor])
   process = tf.keras.Sequential(
             [Rescaling(len(observables))], 
              name=target*"Target"+"Q-values"
             )
   Q_values = process(re_uploading_pqc)
   model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_tensor], 
                          outputs=Q_values)

   return model

   ############################################################

   model = generate_model_Qlearning(qubits, n_layers, n_actions, 
                observables, False)
   model_target = generate_model_Qlearning(qubits, n_layers, 
                n_actions, observables, True)

   model_target.set_weights(model.get_weights())
  

   dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, enable_double_dqn = True, 
                  nb_actions=num_actions, 

   dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])

   history = dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, 
             verbose=2)
```

**The following exception appears:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [119], in <module>
----> 1 dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
      3 history = dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000,
      4 visualize=False,
      5 verbose=2)

File ~.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py:167, in DQNAgent.compile(self, optimizer, metrics)
    164 metrics += [mean_q]  # register default metrics
    166 # We never train the target model, hence we can set the optimizer and loss arbitrarily.
--> 167 **self.target_model = clone_model(self.model, self.custom_model_objects)**
    168 self.target_model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
    169 self.model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')

File ~.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rl/util.py:13, in clone_model(model, custom_objects)
      9 def clone_model(model, custom_objects={}):
     10     # Requires Keras 1.0.7 since get_config has breaking changes.
     11     config = {
     12         'class_name': model.__class__.__name__,
---> 13         **'config': model.get_config(),**
     14     }
     15     clone = model_from_config(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
     16     clone.set_weights(model.get_weights())

File ~.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py:685, in Functional.get_config(self)
    684 def get_config(self):
--> 685   return copy.deepcopy(get_network_config(self))

File ~.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py:1410, in get_network_config(network, serialize_layer_fn)
   1407     node_data = node.serialize(_make_node_key, node_conversion_map)
   1408     filtered_inbound_nodes.append(node_data)
-> 1410 layer_config = serialize_layer_fn(layer)
   1411 layer_config['name'] = layer.name
   1412 layer_config['inbound_nodes'] = filtered_inbound_nodes

File ~.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py:510, in serialize_keras_object(instance)
    507   if _SKIP_FAILED_SERIALIZATION:
    508     return serialize_keras_class_and_config(
    509         name, {_LAYER_UNDEFINED_CONFIG_KEY: True})
--> 510   raise e
    511 serialization_config = {}
    512 for key, item in config.items():

File ~.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py:505, in serialize_keras_object(instance)
    503 name = get_registered_name(instance.__class__)
    504 try:
--> 505   config = instance.get_config()
    506 except NotImplementedError as e:
    507   if _SKIP_FAILED_SERIALIZATION:

File ~.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer_v1.py:497, in Layer.get_config(self)
    494 # Check that either the only argument in the `__init__` is  `self`,
    495 # or that `get_config` has been overridden:
    496 if len(extra_args) > 1 and hasattr(self.get_config, '_is_default'):
--> 497   raise NotImplementedError('Layers with arguments in `__init__` must '
    498                             'override `get_config`.')
    499 return config

NotImplementedError: Layers with arguments in `__init__` must override `get_config`.
```

**the topology:**

[image]

It could be great if this library let us specify the dqn_target instead of doing Clone.
Because working with hybrid neural networks with a cirquit with parameters in a layer, it's difficult to serialize it. So, when it runs the line: **model.get_config()**, it fails.

Any idea to solve it?

Thanks!